# When is there ever an instance in which you can include multiple occurrences of the same element id in a single html document?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

To explain my question further, I'll explain what it is that I'm trying to achieve.

Ok, so I have a contact.php page and I have been adding @media styles to this page's referenced stylesheet. This contact page also has validation javascript running on it which will append 'error' on the end of an input's id in order to display an error regarding that input field.

I have recently added a hidden form within the same fieldset which remains hidden until the screen size gets reduced to a certain width, then the extra form gets displayed while the original one becomes hidden.

With the extra form though, all of the input id's have stayed the same from the original, so I thought the javascript errors would still work the same, but they are not showing at all.

I know that having multiple occurrences of the same element id in the one document is a big no-no, so I've never done it before, which means that I've never faced any issues in this regard.

What I'd like to know the answer to is: would having the input id's occur twice in the same document be causing the javascript errors to not show after the extra form is displayed while the original is changed to hidden?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: remove the hidden one from the dom, you can append it back later if needed.

Comment: Sorry @dandavis could you please elaborate?

Comment: Use your responsive css to alter the first form and don't use a second

Comment: something like `var oldForm=document.forms[0]; oldForm.remove(); ... document.body.appendChild(oldForm);`

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question 
the thing which i observed is in my suggession if you call an html element multiple times with an id it will not called

becoz an id can be called only once in the page to get the value

Instead once declare the class becoz a class can be called multiple times, try once

Its just a try , let me know if it wrks or else we can go for another alternative..
TIA

Comment: If I change the second forms id's to classes instead, won't there be a problem with the server-side validation of the form? I've only ever used an input's id for validation purposes in php. I'm not even sure how I'd call for a class in php...

Comment: at server side validation instead of calling the id #someid call it as as dot(classname which is declared to the html element) you will get it...!!